# Why is the game scene empty when I press "play"?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to open up a game demo from my class to see what it looks like, but after opening up the project in Unity, going to the "Game" tab on the upper part of the screen, and pressing "play", nothing shows up. I'm new to Unity so I have no idea why the screen is blank (there should be a title screen that says "Traffic Jam" and a play button). I'll attach a screenshot of my workspace below.

Note: I read somewhere about changing the "Layout" dropdown option in the upper right corner to "Default", but even if I do that, the title screen doesn't show up correctly.

[image]

Here is a link to the project if you want to try it out yourself:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ekXt948b612dmyT1AZReUOuzh2XbnSDG/view?usp=sharing

UPDATE: I've now opened the scene and have all the objects displayed, however some things still don't seem to be quite right. The title of the game is not shown when it should be and although the "play" button is shown, clicking on it doesn't get the game started as it should.

[image]

Comment: Maybe because you have an empty scene opened? Simply doubleclick the `GameScene` item you have selected in the Assets

Comment: Flagged as should be closed, opening this project I do not get your results, therefore  I cannot reproduce it.  If the answers below are the problem then it is a simple user error and not something covered under the scope of stack overflow.  As your problem is with the tool itself, and not programming related.

Comment: If you have a new Question please open a new question and limit it to one specific coding related question. If your question is not directly coding related you might have more luck at [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: No worries everyone, I've moved the question over to Game Development per the suggestions. I'll close this question on here, but if anyone wants to give my new & updated question a go, this is where it lives now: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/169144/why-is-my-game-not-loading-the-title-screen-correctly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should open the scene you are highlighting, by double clicking. You can also open the unity project by double clicking the scene directly from windows explorer.

[image: file explorer]

When unity has opened that scene, this is what you will see.

[image: scene view]

And this will then be your game view:

[image: game view]

This is what happens when I click play and die.
[image: game over screen]

Comment: No worries! Ah ok, so now that I opened it, I can see most of the objects. However, the title screen seems a little strange; the name of the game doesn't seem to be displaying (only the play button is shown) and nothing seems to happen when I click on the play button. :( Let me add a screenshot in my question to show you a better picture.

Comment: @Karen that is a new problem and should have it's own question.  If this answer solved your initial issue that you asked about be sure to mark it and make a new question for your new problem.

Comment: Hm seems that I can't get to the third screen/can't click play. But I'll keep on trying.

Comment: @Karen I think what you should do is delete your project and  re-download the file from google drive, it should work like that.

Comment: @Livo I've tried that a couple of times already, but I'll try again!

Comment: @Livo Huh strange, when I redownloaded the game, a lot of warning messages appeared on the console (this didn't happen the past few times I tried doing this)

Comment: @Karen, id say create a new question for those and close this one :).

Comment: @Livo Awesome, I'll go ahead and do that, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

After opening a Unity project, ensure you are also opening the correct Unity Scene.
Most Unity project usually contains multiple Scene files which will have different contents.

I can see in your Project tab that you have a Unity scene file which is not currently open, if you double click this it should take you to your scene.

[image: Unity scene file]

I can tell that this is not open as the Hierarchy would show the name of the currently open scene instead of 'Untitled'.

[image]

If this file does not contain the items you are looking for you should check other folder in your project for Unity scene files (did you save it as something else?)

Comment: Ah thank you, let me edit my question above now that I've opened the scene.